# Word Vba : how to get the name of a style in foreign language

Tags: ms-word

"Heading 2" style in French is "Titre 2": how to get "Titre 2" knowing "Heading 2" ?

I searched on Google and found this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/style-namelocal-property-word

Unfortunately that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

When working with the built-in styles always use the enumeration. The code below will print the localized name of Heading 2 to the Immediate window.

```
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2).NameLocal
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdbuiltinstyle-enumeration-word

Answer (score 0):

Also, when your document is going international, and you are using chapter names in the header or footer, don't use

```
{ StyleRef "Heading 1" }
```

because when the document is shown in a German MS Word, it wouldn't understand "Heading" but expect "Überschrift" instead.

However, there's an international version, too. Just use

```
{ StyleRef 1 }
```

without quotes around the heading number.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference "Titre 2" as "Heading 2". Instead, see 'WdBuiltinStyle Enumeration'. Knowing these constants for the most part means you don't need to know the local names and, when you do, you can retrieve them via .NameLocal.

See also 'WdListNumberStyle Enumeration', 'WdCaptionNumberStyle Enumeration', 'WdNoteNumberStyle Enumeration', 'WdApplyQuickStyleSets Enumeration', and 'WdStyleType Enumeration' in the Word VBA help file.